# Try, Catch inside constructor that calls base constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, try-catch

Sorry for the confusing title. Basically I made a BinaryReader class that reads in big endian and set its constructor up as:

```
BinaryReader2(System.IO.Stream strm) : base(strm){}
```

I was told that you can't call the base class's constructor any other way, and that this was the best way to do it.

The problem is that when another program has control of a file I'm trying to read, it doesn't display any error messages (because I'm new to programming and didn't set up any try catch statements..). So, I'm trying to account for all the possible situations by using try-catch statements. I've never used them before, so I was hoping I could get a few pointers on it.

I created the binaryreader2 class in many places throughout the program and was hoping I could set up the try catch inside the binaryreader class itself instead of in each of the places I used it. Is it possible to do that and still call the base class's constructor?

Comment: What *is* the base class? Part of the .NET framework or your own creation?

Comment: If you have the Stream, you have already opened the file - what is it you are trying to guard against here? No: you can't add a try/catch for the duration of a base-ctor call.

Comment: @MarcGravell, Oh yeah, you're right. I pass in a File.Open(path)... Guess I should have seen that one. Thanks for actually answering the question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible workaround: Use composition over inheritance. this way you have a better control on initializing the formerly base object.

Comment: Reference for further reading: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CompositionInsteadOfInheritance

Answer (score 0):

> I've never used them before, so I was hoping I could get a few pointers on it.

- In general put Try/Catch around code that "goes outside" for something. Things your program has no control over. Fetching a file, getting stuff from a database, etc.
- Try-Block as little code as possible. For example wrap just the file fetch call in Try, not all the stuff happening after that. I.E. as @Marc said above, once you have a valid FileStram object there's no point in putting that in the Try block.
- If you do the above you can then Catch very specific exception types. This will allow you to give good error messages about the problem, or otherwise handle the problem in code so your program does not have to just blow up.
- Study carefully the difference between re-throwing the original exception vice throwing a new exception instance.
- Suggestion: Wrap your initial Run() in a Try and in the Catch block do something with it. Learn about "publishing". You can send yourself an email for example. Stuff the exception in a database, write to a log file.
- With the above then in *every* Catch *everywhere* in your application, always re-throw (see my warning above) the exception and you have a single point where you do something useful with it.

Comment: When I tried initializing the filestream inside the try catch statement, it wouldn't let me use it anywhere else because it said it wasn't initialized. Same for when I set it to null initially.

Comment: Not sure what "initializing" means. If you declared it in the try block, then it's scope is limited to that block.